# Recursive Unity Coroutine

Tags: unity, c#, coroutines, recursion

I have a co-routine which is heavily reliant on calling itself to get the task done. I have tested it and the code works fine, the problem is that the co-routine will return every time that it enters itself recursively.

```
IEnumerator test(arg1, arg2)
{
    // I want to pause here
    yield return null;

    // I don't want to pause on any of these
    yield return test(arg1, arg2); 
    yield return test(arg1, arg2);
    yield return test(arg1, arg2);
    yield return test(arg1, arg2);
}
```

In the example above I have a yield return at the top that is hit and pauses the co-routine, thats fine. Then there are the calls to itself below which also pause the co-routine. **How do I avoid pausing the co-routine on the recurcive calls?**

Comment: Since the recursive calls are themselves just IEnumerators, [you can step them manually in a loop as shown here](https://gamedev.stackexchange.com/a/149488/39518), ignoring any unwanted pauses. This looks a bit like an XY problem though, and there might be a more elegant solution to accomplish your original goal. Can you tell us a bit more about the feature this coroutine is serving? We might be able to support that feature in a different way.

Comment: it has to search a grid area to mark enclosed spaces. I had a few other solutions but the problem is that the spaces are irregular. So this essentially propagates itself across all grid tiles that could be linked together, because of the recursion I know that no tiles will be missed.

Comment: That's a start. Please edit your question to include this information, and explain at what points in the graph search you do and don't want it to pause.

Comment: Ahh, yeah that works. Though it does make the code kinda clunky

Comment: It does, that's why I suspect a more elegant solution might be possible if you edit your question to describe the root graph search problem you're trying to solve and how you want that search to behave.

Comment: @DMGregory It's not too bad now I refactored the code that I added and it only added ~10 lines

Comment: If you're happy with the solution then please feel free to post it as an Answer you can Accept. :)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Though the comments on this question I was able to find a solution to this. If I transfer it over to the example I posted above it would look like this:

```
//global valiables
private const int Speed = 200; //amount of iterations per frame
private int skipCount = 0; //counter for the iterations

private IEnumerator PropagateSearch(arg0, arg1)
{
    if ((skipCount = ++skipCount % Speed) == 0)
        yield return null;

    //work here

    {
        IEnumerator count = PropagateSearch(arg0, arg1);
        while (count.MoveNext()) if (skipCount % Speed == 0) yield return null;
    }

    {
        IEnumerator count = PropagateSearch(arg0, arg1);
        while (count.MoveNext()) if (skipCount % Speed == 0) yield return null;
    }

    {
        IEnumerator count = PropagateSearch(arg0, arg1);
        while (count.MoveNext()) if (skipCount % Speed == 0) yield return null;
    }

    {
        IEnumerator count = PropagateSearch(arg0, arg1);
        while (count.MoveNext()) if (skipCount % Speed == 0) yield return null;
    }
}
```

This will go through the co-routine and will only break when there it iterates `Speed` amount of times. With that you can fine tune the amount of work that happens per frame.